# how to send data from one view to another view while using self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, mapkit

I am using [this](https://github.com/digdog/MapKitDragAndDrop) to pin the location.

I have one screen where I am taking inputs as Name, Address, Location.

For Location I am filling data from map with lang and lat.

For that what I am doing is if I click on main screen, I go to another screen (Map Screen) as Push. I pin there location and click Done.

```
- (IBAction)doneAction:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

On clicking done button, I am coming back to main screen where I have written some data. Now what I want to do is when I click Done on Map Screen, I want to write lang and lat in main view controller location label (I know how to read lang and lat.. I just want to write that text in main view controller)

Any idea how to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use delegation to pass that information from the Map view controller to the main one. 
Have a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers), the part "Passing Data Back". You could also use a block in your map view controller as well.

Answer (score 1):

Google for the delegate pattern.

Use the calling view controller as some `locationReceiverDelegate`or so. Then call your delegate from the doneAction Method and pass the loction to a method, that the delegate provides.

Do it properly by defining a protocol that declares all the delegat methods (even if there is just one) and in the setXYdelegate check for the conformity top the protcol using the conformsToProtocol method of NSObject.